# Anaconda Navigator не видит VSCode

Tags: python, anaconda, visual-studio-code

Усановил Navigator, но там не отображается VSCode. Сам Code установлен, даже переустановил. В настройках копался, интерпретатор выбрал в настройках Code.
Подскажите, как вообще их связать..
Облазил англофорумы, провел все эти манипуляции, но всё ещё не сконектилось..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Новая анаконда во время инсталляции предлагает установить VSCode.
Там надо галочку поставить. Если VSCode устанавливается отдельно, они не интегрируются. Итого - удалите VSCode, переустановите анаконду с сайта, взяв последнюю инсталляцию и во время установки заполните чек-бокс.

Comment: Делал, чистил всё, устанавливал со встроенной установкой. Не отображается